# How can I get Google App Script is to push a webhook for each row in my array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a bot (with Zapier's help) to notify different people in Slack with different sets of links once a week, but every time the script run it sends all the messages to the same person with the same link, I'm not able to make the script loop to the different values in my sheet.

In Google Sheets, the column B has de ID of the person and column C has the link for that person

```
function buildReport() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let data = ss.getSheetByName('Team').getRange("B2:C").getValues();
  data.forEach(function(row, index){
  })
  let payload = buildAlert(data);
  sendAlert(payload);
};

function buildAlert(data) {
  let id = data[0][0];
  let link = data[0][1];
    let payload = {
      "blocks": [
        {
          "id": id,
          "link": link
        }
      ]
    };
  return payload;
}

function sendAlert(payload) {
  const webhook = "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/9909120/xxxxxxx/"; 
  var options = {
    "method": "post", 
    "contentType": "application/json", 
    "muteHttpExceptions": true, 
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload) 
  };
  
  try {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhook, options);
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: In Google Sheets, the column B has de ID of the person and column C has the link for that person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You don't have anything in the `forEach` loop

In the `buildReport` function you have these lines:

```js
data.forEach(function(row, index){
})
let payload = buildAlert(data);
sendAlert(payload);
```

The way a `forEach` works is that you pass in a function:

```
data.forEach(function() { /*Function body*/})
```

Now what will happen is that for each item in the `data` variable, the `forEach` will apply the function to it, passing in two arguments, the item and the index. This is why these functions usually handle two arguments

```js
data.forEach(function(item, index){
    console.log(item, index)
})
```

When you `getValues` from a range, your data is in this form:

```
[
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]
```

That is an array of arrays or a 2D array.

When you put this through a `forEach` as above, the output looks like this:

```
[1,2,3] 0
[4,5,6] 1
[7,8,9] 2
```

That is, the item, and the index.

In your code, you don't have anything in the function body. So the `forEach` loops through each row, and does nothing!

You should move the lines into the body of the `forEach` function.

```js
data.forEach(function(row, index){
    let payload = buildAlert(row); // Note that the data is changed to row here.
    sendAlert(payload);
})
```

Then in `buildAlert`, you need to change the code to handle just a 1D array since you are passing in a row, not the whole data.

```js
function buildAlert(row) {
  let id = row[0];
  let link = row[1];
    let payload = {
      "blocks": [
        {
          "id": id,
          "link": link
        }
      ]
    };
  return payload;
}
```

#### Reference

- [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function buildReport() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let data = ss.getSheetByName('Team').getRange("B2:C").getValues();
  data.forEach(function(row, index){
    let payload = buildAlert(row);
    sendAlert(payload);
  });
};

function buildAlert(row) {
  let id = row[0];
  let link = row[1];
  let payload = {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "id": id,
        "link": link
      }
    ]
  };
  return payload;
}
```